# adjust constraint height between UIView and UIButton inside UIScrollView based on phone

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Unfortunately, I've added `UIScrollView` for that Controller because of Content height will be long for small phone such as iPhoneSE and so on.

[image]

You will see there is two constraints between `UIView` and `UIButton`. One is first priority set `1000` and relation is `Less Than or Equal`. Another dotted constraint is second priority set `999` and relation is `Equal`. But that's working smoothly for iPhone 6 onwards. Unfortunately, for iPhoneSE and 5s that gap is awful as two button are under fold. Please let me know how to adjust that constraint for small phone?

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Comment: Select top contriant and set greater than equal and adjust value 10 or 8 ur wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yo can achieve your needs as described constraints in attached image.

**`1. You will need to apply on bottom button.`**

Add same value as bottom constraints with **ScrollView** and **Main** screen's super view (UIView).
As you can see there is applied two bottom constraints over red Button. **(*In attached screenshots)**

Where, One of as bottom constraint on ScrollView (With value = 10) and another one is bottom constraint on Controller's Main View (With same value = 10)

> Please have a look into attached image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with iPhoneSE? Two buttons will be out of file

Comment: Yes dear I have completely made this for you!

Comment: @ppshein It would be great if you will upvote my answer. Thanks!